# how to take a keyspace as a dump in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I need to take a keyspace from the server as a dump and restore that dump to my local cassandra,
I know to do in mysql but how to do in nosql ?
I learn from site that  nodetool ,snapshot and csv file format can achieve this,but I unable to got it ?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with "nodetool". For a good reference documentation take a look here: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/backup_restore

Roughly you need to perform the following steps:

1. take a "snapshot" of the keyspace using: `nodetool snapshot <keyspace-name>`. This is run on the server, where you want to take generates a "snapshot". It will do that, storing a "snapshot" for each table of the keyspace.
2. copy the "snapshots" to your local server. Do this for each keyspace table: `<cassandra-dir>/data/<keyspace-name>/<table-name>/snapshots/` (look for the "latest" taken snapshot - when you take the snapshot it tells you the "name"/"ID" of the snapshot taken).
3. in your local server, before you place the "server" snapshots do the following: stop cassandra, delete the content of that "keyspace"(again for each keyspace table: `<cassandra-dir>/data/<keyspace>/<table-name>/`) and then place the "server" snapshots in each respective "keysapce table" (directly in the `<cassandra-dir>/data/<keyspace>/<table-name>/` and not in the "snapshot" directory).
4. restart the local server, and you should have the data from the server in your local server.

HTH.

Comment: Actually you have to do same operations of copying snapshots for system keyspace

Answer (score 0):

To do this by snapshot..

Command for taking the snapshot-

```
<-path to cassandra's bin folder> nodetool -h <-server host name/ IP> -p <-server port> snapshot
```

This will create a SNAPSHOT directory in VAR folder and this directory contains the snapshot

of server's current database which you can use as dump for your local server.

Answer (score 0):

While `nodetool` is the preferred way, however if you don't have direct access to the underlying file structure, I would recommend using something like: [cassandradump](https://github.com/gianlucaborello/cassandradump)

```sh
$ python cassandradump.py --keyspace system --export-file dump.cql
Exporting schema for keyspace system
Exporting schema for column family system.peers
Exporting data for column family system.peers
Exporting schema for column family system.range_xfers
Exporting data for column family system.range_xfers
Exporting schema for column family system.schema_columns
Exporting data for column family system.schema_columns
...
```